# Send Firebase Cloud Messaging to mobile phone devices

Tags: php, android, curl, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I just developed a sample of firebase with apps server in my live webserver.

I tried it on my localhost pc (offline) and firebase notification are sent on virtual devices android.

But when i try to install apk file into my phone devices and transfer PHP file into my live server (i.e www.aaa.com).

Firebase notification does not work at all. it doesn't send into my phone devices.

Am i missing something on the code ? . The code as below. Thanks.

```
<?php
require "connect.php";
global $con;
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        $message     = $_POST['message'];
        $title       = $_POST['title'];
        $path_to_fcm = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'; 
        $server_key  = "SERVER KEY HERE";
        echo "Data sent ! <br/>";

        $sql = "SELECT fcm_token FROM fcm_info";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
            $key = $row[0];
        $headers = array('Authorization:key=' .$server_key, 'Content-Type:application/json');
        $fields  = array('to' => $key, 'notification' => array('title' => $title, 'body'=> $message));
        $payload = json_encode($fields);
        $curl_session = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $path_to_fcm);
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
        $result = curl_exec($curl_session);
        curl_close($curl_session);
        mysqli_close($con);
    }   
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Send Notification</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action='send_notification.php' method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Title : </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="title" required="required" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Message : </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="message"  required="required" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send notification"></td>

            </tr>
        </table> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have to set SERVER KEY HERE??

Comment: DId you try from server to virtual device or from localhost to real device? To be sure the problem is in server not android device

Comment: already set the server key there. :) .. . i just dont want to display server key

Comment: already tried in two different server http and https . . version 2008 and 2012. both gave the same result (does not send the notification) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
$header=array('Content-Type: application/json',
"Authorization: key=YOUR KEY");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{ \"notification\": {    \"body\": \"Weather Forecast\",
    \"title\": \"YOur title\",
    \"to\" : \"YOUR DEVICE REG TOKEN\"}"

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: whole response is ? this means message id generated

Comment: yes. message id appear but firebase notification did not appear on real devices and also virtual devices

Comment: you change data to notification? and  \"to\" : \"/topics/NeonGRP\"}" to your regestration token?

Comment: is it like this ? curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{ \"notification\": {    \"body\": \"Weather Forecast\",
             \"idd\": \"2\" ,
             \"click_action\": \"CsAC\",
             \"sound\": \"not\",
             \"picture_url\": \"http://opsbug.com/static/google-io.jpg\",
             \"icon\": \"spinne\"  },
             \"to\" : \"/topics/NeonGRP\"              }");

Comment: It work from live server to virtual devices . it does not work when it try to send into real devices . I don't know why .

Comment: check your real device reg token. may be it refreshed and new token generated

Comment: i can send the firebase notfication using firebase to real devices . but i cannot send it using web browser to real devices . .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129858/discussion-between-divyesh-and-jamilah).

Comment: for web interface you need to use advanced tab to send message

Answer (score -1):

go to your firebase console the project settings> select second tab 'cloud messaging' there would be your server key which your will need in your php file ;)